# Summation with values in a dictionary (Python)

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop

I am struggling with using summation in Python.

I obtain input, which is then autocorrected and all punctuation is removed:

```
text=input("Enter your text here: )
```

Then, I have a dictionary:

```
bread = {"bread": 7, "sourdough crusts": 10}
```

I determined if any key from `bread` existed in `text` with the code:

```
result = re.findall('|'.join(bread), text)
```

I want to find the sum of all the values, should the corresponding key exist in `text`. At the moment, my code looks like this:

```
for sentence, rating in bread.items():
     ssum = 0
     for i in range(len(result)):
           ssum = ssum + rating
print("Sum: " + str(ssum))
```

However, this produces incredibly random results. For example, if

```
text = bread sourdough crusts
```

It says that

```
ssum = 20
```

(even though it should equal 17).

What is going on here, and how do I fix it?

Comment: Can you provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: I don't think your problem is related to calculating the sum of values. Your problem is in *which values* you choose.

Comment: @mkrieger1 What do you mean?

Comment: @matszwecja I have edited the question to make it more user-friendly.

Comment: please provide couple of example of your input and output

Comment: I mean that you are correctly using `a + b` to calculate the sum of `a` and `b`. Your problem is that you are using the wrong values for `a` and `b`.

Comment: @mkrieger1 how do you know this, and how can I fix it?

Comment: The code for summing is correct, so the problem must be somewhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By adding `print(ssum)` after the add you might get a good idea what is going on and why the result is "random".

```
7
14
10
20
Sum: 20
```

Each sentence rating is added `len(result)` times, but you are assigning `ssum = 0` on each loop iteration, so you return only the last one.
Instead, you want to simply *check* if the `sentence` is found in `result` and assign `ssum` outside the loop

```
import re

text = "bread sourdough crusts"
bread = {"bread": 7, "sourdough crusts": 10}
result = re.findall('|'.join(bread), text)
ssum = 0
for sentence, rating in bread.items():
    if sentence in result:
        ssum = ssum + rating
print("Sum: " + str(ssum))
```

Answer (score -1):

The algorithm you wrote is incorrect. You can use this code

```py
import re

text=input("Enter your text here: ") # "bread sourdough crusts"
bread = {"bread": 7, "sourdough crusts": 10}
result = re.findall('|'.join(bread), text) # ['bread', 'sourdough crusts']

ssum = 0
for i in result:
    ssum += bread[i]

print(ssum) # 17
```